# Where is assistant editor gone?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, assistant

i cant find how to turn on Assistant Editor in XCode 4.

On tutorial examples i see special button https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUAYe.png
in Editor panel:
http:// i.stack.imgur.com/yspVC.png

But i cant find Editor panel in my copy of XCode:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwdnm.png

Something going wrong, i think.
What can i do to switch to split screen mode (assistant editor)?

P.S.: Sorry for links on images instead of real one. And for one broken link, its all about spam prevetion system and lack of reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are running Xcode 3, not Xcode 4.

Comment: Holly crap, you right! XCode 3.2 lack such functionality? My task is to bind events from UI controls to some functions in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not running XC4 in that screen shot.